# how to move the physical location of the permalink header in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Does anyone know how to move the physical location of a permalink header in wordpress? I dont want it to be the first thing that is seen but rather I want a shortcode item there.

Answer (score 0):

In your page.php you can delete the php function for calling the header ( the_header() ) and put the function to call the shortcode ( do_shortcode() ).

This way the page is not embeding the header.php but get the code of your shortcode at this place of your markup.

Page Template:

You can create a page template in your theme-folder. For this, you can simple duplicate the page.php and call it page-yourname.php. At the top of your page you add the name of the page template:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```

In that file you do the adjustments that you like to do with the shortcode.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

With the template structure of wordpress, the template will automatically be found at the edit screen of your pages. It will be found on the right side under "page attributes".

You can set the template for your individual pages. So your adjustments to the template will only affect your pages, where you selected the template in the page attributes.

Comment: thanks. Would this apply only to one page or all? And then how do I locate the page to do this since it is all controlled by the DB?

Comment: I edited my answer, you can use page templates for that, which you can set in a dropdown to your pages